# 500 Internal server error while counting dynamic json data in Azure http trigger post method

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, azure-functions, json.net

I am creating a Azure function http trigger post method where i am receiving json data in body and then i am  mapping it and store it in blob storage.It is working well in local but in Azure environment it gets failed.In application insight i have created a custom log events where i see the error is due to counting of json dynamic data.
error:Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
***Here is my sample code***
public async Task Run([ HttpTrigger(  AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null) ] HttpRequest req )
{

```
        try
        {
            StringBuilder csveventcontent = new StringBuilder();

            string requestBody =
                await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

             int eventsDataloopCount = json["body"]["data"].Count;
```

*******Sample http reqst data*******
{
"functionName": "abc",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {},
"body": {
"data": [
{
"item1": 1,
"created_at": "2021-02-10T21:07:08Z",
"item2":"b",
"item3": -1,
"item4": null,
"item5": null,
"arrayitem": {
"item1": "1",
"item2": "2",
"item3": "3"
},
"data": {},
"arrayevent": {
"abc": 1
}
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see there are two issues in your JSON.

1. It should be `"item2": "b"` not `"item2": b`.
2. There are two keys for `"item1"` for value `"1"` and `"3"`. so you have to remove one of them.

So my suggestion is to first fix the JSON and then proceed further.

Got the issue, you should use `json["body"]["data"].Count` not `json["body"]["data"].count`. `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` has no count method.

Comment: sorry that was mine mistake while sharing data .it is corrected now and req that m getting is correct i guess.

Comment: Can you try json.body.data?

Comment: Error message:Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: @shashankshekhar check the updated answer

Comment: Yes i tried ..but i still get the same error..it is executing in local..i tried with postman but not on azure.
Message Exception while executing function: EventsMappedFunction Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference 
Exception type Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException 
Failed method EventsMappedFunction.EventsMappedFunction+<Run>d__4.MoveNext

Comment: Actually m connecting my function app in azure data factory and it gets failed there.But in local it is running .Exception that i posted is coming after count .I am unable to find this root cause.

Comment: @shashankshekhar you have to provide the complete information about your issue, otherwise it is very difficult for someone to help you. and when posting the question, make sure you are posting the actual running code.

Comment: yes i agree with you..but this is complete code from where exception is coming.
After this m mapping and convertting into csv .Everything is functioning well in Local but in application insight it is showing error at this count line.
In ADF error showing is :Call to provided Azure function 'EventsMappedFunction' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35